# Can I have Windows use additional HOSTS entries from a file server?

Tags: windows, hosts-file

I have a network of computers and a server. I often need to edit the hosts file of all the computers to add a new entry or to change one.
e.g.

```
192.168.1.101 temporary-internal-site
```

How can I get all the machines (all windows) to 'import' or use a hosts file on a server in addition to the normal one. This means that I can just edit this one file with the new entry and all the machines will check it.

Feel free to ask questions if you don't understand.

Comment: If you have home router (for example WLAN box or similar), you can probably add those entries to there as DNS records, instead of HOSTS. That way every computer in your network can have same entries, without syncronizing files between computers.

Comment: Yes I do have a router, but not sure what I need to edit or where? I have a DLINK  DIR-615

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but [OpenDNS shortcuts](https://www.opendns.com/solutions/household/shortcuts/) might help a bit. (I've never used it; I hope they allow mapping `temporary-internal-site` to `http://192.168.1.101`. However, it would NOT get you a correct HTTP `Host` header.)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do had been done a while ago, its called DNS zones and you need a DNS daemon/service to respond request. 
The DNS upload zones (text files) from another file systems or DNS servers.

So, you have to set up a DNS Server. OpenDNS is a good place to start.