# Global Hosts file WINDOWS

Tags: windows, hosts-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have Windows use additional HOSTS entries from a file server?](https://superuser.com/questions/244979/can-i-have-windows-use-additional-hosts-entries-from-a-file-server)

How can I set up a global windows hosts file on my network. I have a server store the file on.

Comment: Since search engines lead to here: The location of it is "`%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`" or "`%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`"  (usually "`C:\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`")

Answer (score 4):

Hosts files are always local. If you want a global repository, use a dns server

Comment: That requires all machines on the network to use that server as a DNS server.  There's a simpler way using a GPO to share the hosts file

Comment: @Foo Bah : GPO requires AD which requires a DNS server, doesn't it ?

Comment: @sfk AD requires DNS but there are ways to do GPO without AD.

Comment: to push out GPO changes, you need AD.  This isn't possible with a WORKGROUP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the windows version, the file can be in a few locations.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system

Comment: **this doesn't really answer the question**

Comment: A group policy object can be used to distribute files, but it really depends on the network setup.

Comment: Hosts files are always local. If you want a global repository, use a dns server

Comment: @sfk: make that an answer, that is the real answer.